# How can I change every url in rss box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, youtube

I have a wordpress site which can be found here:
http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/
On the right side you can see this links:
[image]

This urls camed from my youtube rss chanel (uploads playlist) which url is this:

> https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCxnFBx6UhZS25Poa5-ZeeNg

I would like to modified this links for I can show videos in lightbox.
For example I would like to turn in to this link:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=2&v=yYNcwFIwCpU

to this:

> http://www.youtube.com/embed/yYNcwFIwCpU?autoplay=1

So I writed a script for it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  
        str = jQuery("#rss-4 ul li a").attr("href");
        jQuery("#rss-4 ul li a").each(function() {
        jQuery("#rss-4 ul li a").attr("href",str.replace(/(youtube.com)\/watch\?v\=|(youtu.be)\//g, "youtube.com/embed/"));
        jQuery( '#rss-4 ul li a' ).attr( 'href', function(index, value) {
        return value + '?autoplay=1';
        });
        //Lightview class need for the lightbox
        jQuery("#rss-4 ul li a").addClass("lightview");
         });
});
```

Unfortunetly this script dosen't do the right thing.
**What it does?**
The script replace all links url **to the newest video url** (the first item on the list).
In this case reaplace all url to

> "Puzsér szár aranyért sem adná"

link url.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `each` to loop over all instances, however within `each` you are setting all links to the same url.

Also, the value you store in `str` is the href of the first matching selector.

`this` within `each` is the instance of the element collection so try:

```
jQuery("#rss-4 ul li a").each(function() {
        var str = this.href;
        str = str.replace(/(youtube.com)\/watch\?v\=|(youtu.be)\//g, "youtube.com/embed/");
         str +='?autoplay=1';
         // only change the current element
        jQuery(this).attr("href", str);            
});
```

--OR using `attr(function)`

```
jQuery("#rss-4 ul li a").attr('href',function(_, oldHref) {
        var str = oldHref.replace(/(youtube.com)\/watch\?v\=|(youtu.be)\//g, "youtube.com/embed/");
         str +='?autoplay=1';
         return str;           
});
```

Comment: Ah thank you it's working!
You missed the class from the script but it's fine now!

Comment: can chain that to the end of either of these, or use `$(this)` as well inside either loop